# How remove Ebean ORM Entity property

Tags: java, entity-framework, hibernate, ebean

In java model Entity have the below property

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "device_key")
public class UserKey implements Serializable {
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "device_id")
    private int deviceId;

    @Column(name = "device_hub_id")
    private int serverId;

    private byte status;

    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private int peopleSeq; //人员序号

    private short tempSeq; //临时证

    @Column(name = "from_date")
    private String startDate;

    @Column(name = "to_date")
    private String endDate;

    @Column(name = "from_time")
    private String startTime;

    @Column(name = "to_time")
    private String endTime;

    private String peopleName;

    private short attr;
}
```

but in DB table only have a part of property

```
CREATE TABLE `device_key` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `device_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `device_hub_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `from_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `to_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `from_time` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `to_time` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK_key_device` (`device_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_key_device` FOREIGN KEY (`device_id`) REFERENCES `device` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=25 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

I want to know in ebean how to remove some property use annotation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `@Transient` annotation

> **Transient Fields** Transient entity fields are fields that do not participate in persistence and their values are never stored in the
>   database (similar to transient fields in Java that do not participate
>   in serialization). Static and final entity fields are always
>   considered to be transient. Other fields can be declared explicitly as
>   transient using either the Java transient modifier (which also affects
>   serialization) or the JPA @Transient annotation (which only affects
>   persistence):
>
> ```
> @Entity
> public class EntityWithTransientFields {
>     static int transient1; // not persistent because of static
>     final int transient2 = 0;  // not persistent because of final
>     transient int transient3; // not persistent because of transient
>     @Transient int transient4; // not persistent because of @Transient
> }
> ```
>
> The above entity class contains only transient (non persistent) entity
>   fields with no real content to be stored in the database.